# variable return null after method finished

Tags: java, android, firebase-mlkit

im trying to make a function that translate a text and print the result. im using firebasetranslator.

by debugging, the app starts but the textbox is empty. trying to put a marker on

```
private void setRisultato(String string){
            this.risultato = string;
}
```

I see that the translated text is correctly assigned to the result variable.
but if I put the marker up

```
public String getRisultato(){
    return risultato;
}
```

I see what result is null (not empty), can someone explain me why?

UPDATE:

Traduttore.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.ml.common.modeldownload.FirebaseModelDownloadConditions;
import com.google.firebase.ml.naturallanguage.FirebaseNaturalLanguage;
import com.google.firebase.ml.naturallanguage.translate.FirebaseTranslateLanguage;
import com.google.firebase.ml.naturallanguage.translate.FirebaseTranslator;
import com.google.firebase.ml.naturallanguage.translate.FirebaseTranslatorOptions;


public class Traduttore extends Activity {
    private static String text1;

    public interface callbacktranslate {
        void onCallback(String risultato);
    }
    public void traduci(String textblock, final callbacktranslate callback){
        //clear string and start translate
        String blocktext = textblock.replaceAll("\n"," ");
        String blocktext2 = blocktext.replaceAll("\\.","");
        String blocktext3 = blocktext2.toUpperCase();
        text1 = blocktext3;
        downloadTranslatorAndTranslate(callback);
    }
    public void translateText(FirebaseTranslator langTranslator, final callbacktranslate callback) {
        //translate source text to english
        langTranslator.translate(text1).addOnSuccessListener(
                        new OnSuccessListener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(@NonNull String translatedText) {
                                //make variable all uppercase and save it
                                String blocktext4 = translatedText.toUpperCase();
                                callback.onCallback(blocktext4);
                            }
                        })
                .addOnFailureListener(
                        new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            }
                        });
    }
    public void downloadTranslatorAndTranslate(final callbacktranslate callback) {
        int sourceLanguage = 11; //language source(en=11)
        //create translator for source and target languages
        FirebaseTranslatorOptions options =
                new FirebaseTranslatorOptions.Builder()
                        .setSourceLanguage(sourceLanguage)
                        .setTargetLanguage(FirebaseTranslateLanguage.IT)
                        .build();
        final FirebaseTranslator langTranslator =
                FirebaseNaturalLanguage.getInstance().getTranslator(options);
        //download language models if needed
        FirebaseModelDownloadConditions conditions = new FirebaseModelDownloadConditions.Builder()
                .build();
        langTranslator.downloadModelIfNeeded(conditions)
                .addOnSuccessListener(
                        new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void v) {
                                translateText(langTranslator,callback);
                            }
                        })
                .addOnFailureListener(
                        new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            }
                        });
    }
}
```

method in MainActivity.java:

```
public ConstraintLayout vpp;
public TextView[] textViewArray = new TextView[500];
public int i;

public void StartReadImage(){
    FirebaseVisionImage image2 = FirebaseVisionImage.fromBitmap(resizedBitmap);
    FirebaseVisionTextRecognizer textRecognizer2 = FirebaseVision.getInstance()
            .getOnDeviceTextRecognizer();
    final Task<FirebaseVisionText> result2 =
            textRecognizer2.processImage(image2)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FirebaseVisionText>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(FirebaseVisionText firebaseVisionText) {
                            // Task completed successfully
                           i = 0;
                            resultText = firebaseVisionText.getText();

                            for (FirebaseVisionText.TextBlock block: firebaseVisionText.getTextBlocks()) {
                                String blockText = block.getText();
                                Float blockConfidence = block.getConfidence();
                                List<RecognizedLanguage> blockLanguages = block.getRecognizedLanguages();

                                final  Point[] blockCornerPoints = block.getCornerPoints();
                                final  Rect blockFrame = block.getBoundingBox();

                                traduttore.traduci(blockText, new Traduttore.callbacktranslate() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onCallback(String result) {
                                        createCover(blockCornerPoints, blockFrame, result, i);
                                        i++;
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(
                            new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                    // Task failed with an exception
                                }
                            });
}
public void createCover(Point[] CornerPoint,Rect blockFrame,String blockText, int i){

            textViewArray[i] = new TextView(context);
            textViewArray[i].setTextSize(9);
            textViewArray[i].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            textViewArray[i].setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            textViewArray[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(225, 225, 225));
            textViewArray[i].setHeight(blockFrame.height());
            textViewArray[i].setWidth(blockFrame.width());
            textViewArray[i].setX(CornerPoint[0].x);
            textViewArray[i].setY(CornerPoint[0].y);

            textViewArray[i].setText(blockText);
            vpp.addView(textViewArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: Because the *asynchronous* `translate()` method hasn't completed the translation yet, so the Success Listener hasn't been called yet (or it failed). --- Actually, the *asynchronous* download hasn't even completed yet, so the `translateText()` method hasn't been called yet. --- Your `Traduciblocco()` method cannot get the result synchronously. Re-think your logic.

Comment: have a look at this for some help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/how-to-get-data-from-any-asynchronous-operation-in-android

Comment: If you see the setter get called and assign the variable correctly but then in the getter it's null, you may be running into a problem with the risultato variable being static and therefore shared across all instances of the class and you are overwritting it somewhere.

Comment: oh okay, clear, now I try to fix it, I think I understand.. thanks!

Comment: by following the guide to implement callback i've edited the code in post but i dont understanding how to call variable now.. its correct what i have done?

Comment: With your changes, the callback is null, so you're getting a NullPointerException?

Comment: @cricket_007 yes.. Is that right what I've done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to set the callback somewhere, and in order to do that, you'll need to add it a few places, and pass it on appropriately

```
traduci(String textblock, final Callback callback)

downloadTranslatorAndTranslate(final Callback callback)

translateText(FirebaseTranslator langTranslator, final Callback callback)
```

From there, you need to add the callback to the Activity method call, and that method should be void since the callback comes later from when the method actually returns

```
public void Traduciblocco(String abc){
    traduttore.traduci(abc, new Callback() {
        @Override 
        public void onCallback(String result) {
            // resultTxt.setText(result); 
        } 
    });
}
```

Comment: i've edited again code on post, but now it gives me another error: "error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype" on @Override at TraduciBlocco on MainActivity and "error: incompatible types: <anonymous javax.security.auth.callback.Callback> cannot be converted to com.test.testTraduttore.Traduttore.Callback" in fact onCallback is as never used,should instead refer to the onCallback in translator.java right?

Comment: Look at the import statements and use the correct Callback class

Comment: ok i solved that problem, now the variable returns correctly, the problem is that i have to insert that string in an array of textview created programmatically but if i create all textview inside callbackmethod, all textview takes as text the same, exactly only the last text.. but if i put all code outside callback method(without translation), all textviews have our text, what could be the reason? i've updated code at post

Comment: Well, in the callback you're always making a new array. That would be one problem. So move the array definition out of the callback, then only do the i++ inside the onCallback

Comment: trying to put definition on the class definitions, the result is the same(to be sure i edit code in post again

Comment: same result if i call onCallback inside other async, inside for cycle, before call createCover()

Comment: I tried many other things,including making the translation as task and trying with the whenAll, or trying to pass everything to another class first and then calling the variables later but I still haven't finded a solution. the problem is always the last one, that is that each array takes the last textblock, if I put the marker on the callback call, on debug, at the beginning of that call, the variable has as value the last string of the for-loop that returns the strings in individual blocks,how can i fix it? i've updated code

Comment: Now every time an image is processed, you're resetting i = 0; so having an array of 500 values wouldn't be populated... Why not just use an Arraylist and add TextViews to it rather than maintain the index variable?

Comment: mh, thats right for the future of this project, but right now i only process 1 image, i=0 is before for-loop and infact arrays are created correctly and had a different i for all textview. atm the problem i think is on callback(maybe?), because not give the correct string inside createCover

Comment: i tried now to remove callback interface and make a save/load method for sharedpreferences but same thing.. i dont understand where is the problem but in any situation, all strings have always only the last arrayblock text..

Comment: I think you should add a few `Log.info` call into `onSuccess` and `onCallback` for at least the text, then run the app normally to see what order things happen in.  That way, you're not having separate threads being blocked by running the debugger

Comment: by removing text1 from traduttore.java and pass string from the first method to the task for translate string, now all works! finally! thanks you so much for all your support and time!